# Should you use the schema name in WHERE, ON, and other clauses?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I know it is good practice, and a performance boost, in SQL Server to prefix the table name with the schema (`dbo.TableName`) in the `FROM` clause of a `SELECT` statement but should you also use it on other clauses like the `WHERE` or `ON`? Should you also specify the `TABLE` name for `columns` in the where clause if the column name is unique?

Take two scenarios:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM dbo.Table
WHERE Col1 = Value;
```

and

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3,
FROM dbo.Table
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2
ON Col1 = Col5
WHERE Col6 = Value;
```

In the first scenario should I add `dbo.Table` to each column name?

IN the second scenario if I added an alias to each table would that automatically include the schema data too or would I still need to pre-fix the column names with the schema.

And in both scenarios do I even NEED to prefix the columns with schema data or is that pointless and gives no performance boost at all?

Comment: Include the schema name in the `FROM` clause, and use table aliases.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why I should use aliases?

Comment: Refer to Aaron's write up on using table aliases (https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @Kin I understand why you should use aliases but in a single table `select` why should I use an alias? Do aliases also include the schema if you include it? A bit more reasoning behind the use of aliases as it pertains to my question would be nice.

Comment: Using Aliases is a matter of code readability. For eg. `select column1, column2 from table1` would not generally need an alias vs `select t1.column1, t2.column1, t2.column2 from dbo.table1 as t1 inner join dbo.table2 as t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID` is where it makes sense to use Aliases.

Comment: @Kin Like I said, I understand the purpose of Aliases but no one is answering my question of if I should use table name and schema names when calling/referencing columns in the `select where on` clauses. I will edit my question to give examples in hopes it will help you understand.

Comment: @ypercube You still did not answer the question of does the alias include the schema info and how does that pertain to simple `select` statements where it is kind of stupid to use an aliases, see scenario 1 in my question.

Comment: @ypercube Yes that is what I was asking. When I asked if an alias contained the schema info I mean did it only contain a reference to `table` or to `DB.dbo.Table` If you want to put a answer together based off that I will use it to accept for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM dbo.Table
WHERE Col1 = Value;
```

> In the first scenario should I add dbo.Table to each column name?

For single tables, table aliases are OK to be excluded.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3,
FROM dbo.Table
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2
ON Col1 = Col5
WHERE Col6 = Value;
```

> IN the second scenario if I added an alias to each table would that automatically include the schema data too or would I still need to pre-fix the column names with the schema.

Table alias will include the FULLY qualified table name.

e.g. `dbo.Table as T1` will reference the `dbo.Table`.

> And in both scenarios do I even NEED to prefix the columns with schema data or is that pointless and gives no performance boost at all?

First your query example is wrong. It should be (carefully see the aliases I have used, else it will be syntactically wrong - SQL Server will throw errors).

```
 SELECT T1.Col1, T1.Col2, T2.Col3,
    FROM dbo.Table T1
    INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 T2
    ON T1.Col1 =  T2.Col5
    WHERE T2Col6 = Value;
```

Hopefully, the above query will answer your 3rd question as well.